# Rotate an object using ARCore Frame.Pose in unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, quaternions, arcore

I'm creating and indoor navigation app for exercise using ARCore and Unity.

The app is pretty similar to the one at this url [Navigation App Using ARCore](https://community.arm.com/developer/tools-software/graphics/b/blog/posts/indoor-real-time-navigation-with-slam-on-your-mobile#update)

The major difference is that the camera follows the pointer from above and the pointer is an arrow. There is also another object (a red cube) that shows how the phone is oriented.

I've successfully obtained the pose rotation from phone and used it on the red cube with:

```
myRedCube.transform.rotation = Frame.Pose.rotation;
```

Now I need to rotate the arrow only on x-z plane according to phone movement to let the user see where he was going(with the camera looking at the pointer from above). If I set a fixed angle it works perfectly fine but if I use the angle from ARCore the rotation is not the same as I expected.

I've tried to extract the y euler angle of the Frame.Pose.rotation and used with:

```
arrow.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0,myYAngle,0);
```

but the rotation is not right.

Another test that I've done is using an oriented vector passed to LookRotation:

```
Vector3 tempVector = Quaternion.AngleAxis(myYAngle, Vector3.up) * Vector3.forward;
arrow.transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(tempVector);
```

And also in this case the arrow doesn't respect the rotation on x-z plane. 
In these two examples myYAngle is obtained from Frame.Pose.rotation.eulerAngles property.

I'm probably missing something between the extraction of the quaternion and the application of the new rotation.

Could someone explain me how to manipulate rotation quaternion from Frame.Pose to have the desired effect? Other suggested methods are welcome. I'm using a Samsung Galaxy S9 for testing the app.

[image]

Comment: Did you try [this](https://forum.unity.com/threads/rotate-2d-image-for-map-like-3d-player-rotation.448743/)

Comment: Yes, the behavihour is similar to my first attempt, but when I roll the phone the arrow has an unexpected rotation. I need only to rotate the arrow during yaw and avoid the rotation during pitch and roll.